# Xamarin.iOS: Create a custom button with an additional object

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

In my Xamarin.iOS application there are many buttons with the same scheme but different from to standart UIButton. I created one class for the buttons because most of the features are same but for example the textcolor or the backgroundcolor are different.

So how can I put an extra information about any button in the storyboard?
And how can I react on it in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your custom element visible in for the designer with the `DesignTimeVisible` and the `Register` Attribute like

```
[Register ("CustomButton"), DesignTimeVisible (true)]
public class CustomButton: UIButton {

    [Export ("CustomProperty "), Browsable (true)]
    public int CustomProperty {get; set;}

    public CustomButton(IntPtr handle) : base (handle) { }

    public CustomButton()
    {
        // Called when created from code.
        Initialize ();
    }

    public override void AwakeFromNib ()
    {
        // Called when loaded from xib or storyboard.
        Initialize ();
    }

    void Initialize ()
    {
        // Common initialization code here.
        CustomProperty = 0xB00B5;
    }
}
```

For all properties that you want to set in the Designer you just hae to add `Export` and `Browsable (true)`. In the `Initialize`you can set all the vlaues of the common properties.

It will appear in the Toolbox under `Custom Components`. You might have to rebuild.
[image]

And the Custom Property can be modified in the `Properties` pane

[image]

More info: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_overview/